# freshly installed Android Emulator keeps saying settings, google has stopped working in Parallel Desktop

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, parallels

I am using windows in Mac Pro. In Windows Parallel Desktop I am keep on getting error message in Android Emulator like:

1. Google has stooped working
2. Settings has stopped working.
3. Pixel Launcher has stopped working.

Getting error message in freshly installed Xamarin tools in Visual Studio.

Googling suggested to clear the cache or force stop it, but nothing is working

[image]

Comment: Based on your description, this issue was related to the Nested Virualazion, did you enable the `Enable Nested Virtualization ` like following link.https://kb.parallels.com/en/116239

Comment: Yeah, I did it. For now I fixed by running emulator in Mac and project in Windows. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I installed **Android Studio on Mac** and running project on Windows. By Following below link I ran few commands and Windows able to communicate with MAC

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/connect-android-emulator-mac-windows

Not sure if this is right way. But running virtual device inside virtual machine is giving some problem.

Above thing is working fine. Let me know if there is any other best solution for this.